# EF5 How to map and submit related data corretly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapping, many-to-many, relationship

I have two models with a many to many relationship:

```
public class Reference
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reference> References { get; set; }
}
```

On my view for the creation for my `Reference` entry I have multiple drop down list listing available `Categories`. That means on the creation of a `Reference` multiple existing `Categories` can be related to the `Reference` (through a relations table obvious).

Now here's what a normal ActionResult for submitting the data would look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Reference reference)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.References.Add(reference);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Running this code will result in new `Categories` being created. A relation between those new `Categories` and the new `Reference` is created. And `Category.Name` is set to the `SelectedValue` from the drop down lists.

**How would you make sure the data is mapped and submitted correctly?**

Comment: You need to Attach category. When you add the Reference the corresponding Category is also added what leads to creating duplicates. Attach category and then add the Reference.

Comment: @Pawel - That makes sense. But where do I attach it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: 'db.Categories`? Probably loop all reference.Categories and do db.Categories.Attach(category). You are not showing your context so I don't know if you have the Categories property but I assume you have a property like this otherwise you would not be able to show categories on your page..

Comment: @Pawel - Alright so I loop through it and attach them. Anything else?

Comment: If you use attach on the categories they will need their PK populated first, (its actually the only bit you need ie you could avoid using name completely) If PK isn't populated a new entity will probably be created.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Alright. How will I do that? Because yes you're right this throughs a key error

Comment: You have 2 options, query it based on name, or store the ID in the dropdown (normally in the value field of the dd list). The first is slow (but you could cache this on the server if you need) and the second allows IDs to be seen by the users (by inspecting page source, in most cases probably not a big deal). I personally normally go for the second option

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Sure i'm aware of that. But how can I get the selected value from the drop down into my controller and add as Id on the attach?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - I should probably mention my drop downs looks like this: `<input type='select' name='Categories[0].Name'/>`. Maybe that not right? Should I remove .Name?

Comment: Off the top of my head you need to bind the dropdownlist manually with the modelbinder so that it uses the selectedvalue field as the one bound to your model. Im not sure if there is an easier way to do this in MVC4 or not, its been a while since ive done this

Comment: You will also need value='Categories[0].Id' I think...

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Yep already have the value set to Id. And yes manually binding the selected value makes sense. I just have no idea how to.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Please post the your last + second last comment as an answer. That was actually it! I had .Name on the select element instead of .Id. I manually looped through it and binded them, and the new categories was actually not created.

Comment: @KasperSkov looks like you did something different to what i was suggesting to solve your problem, perhaps you should post what you did as an answer to the question?